# Using sql transactions

Tags: c#, sql, vb.net, winforms, transactions

I've just began to learn using transactions in my application when running multiple queries.

I've successfully done it but I have some question and concern.

So far i've only tried in sql server, While debugging my program I noticed that I can't access the table while the transaction hasn't finished. Opening the table in sql server management studio gives me a Timeout expired error. Is it possible to prevent this? would the same happen in an oracle database?

Another concern, how does transactions affect triggers? does the trigger execute only when I call `Transaction.Commit()`?

Comment: Regarding your question about the database being locked during a transaction, take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx It seems you may be interested in using `READ UNCOMMITTED`

Comment: It's odd that you can't access the table. Normally it's either page level or row level locking on the database. If you're trying to access those records, then read uncommitted should work for you. The triggers should fire as normal, but you really do want to test what happens yourself, to see if there is anything untoward happening.

Comment: Have you done update on entire table? Did you open table under same credentials as your running code?  With oracle no problems. You will read data that is committed. Uncommitted data will be only available to the session you're in. Triggers will execute. Any data changes will be written to rollback log, just like if it wasn't trigger.

Comment: transactions don't really effect the running of triggers, the triggers are simply part of the transaction. If you rollback, the changes the trigger did in the db are also rolled back.